# Android tag a friend or page in my photo on facebook

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook SDK3.0 , and i want to post a photo on my photos and tag a "Friend/Page" in it.

I've seen that we MUST provide a place with the tag parameter, and i'm some how confused about that, what is the place should be..?!

### And is there another way to tag a "Friend/Page" on my photo..?!

### My code:-

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putParcelable(PICTURE_PARAM, image);
parameters.putString("tags", PAGE_ID);
parameters.putString("place", ??????);
parameters.putString("message", comment );
String graphPath = MY_PHOTOS;
Session activeSession = Session.getActiveSession();
Request postToPageRequest = new Request(activeSession, graphPath);
postToPageRequest.setParameters(parameters);
postToPageRequest.setHttpMethod(HttpMethod.POST);
postToPageRequest.executeAsync();
```

Thanks,

Comment: Still no answers or suggestions:(

Answer (score 0):

### After along search, i found that :-

- We can add the "place" parameter is just a string containing an ID to that place ,

  ---

  You can find the city ID from the Facebook pages for each city "i.e
  http://www.facebook.com/pages/Cairo-Egypt/115351105145884".

  Cairo_ID = 115351105145884.

---

- Also the "tags" is a String list no a string.

  parameters.putStringArray("tags", new String[]{PAGE_ID});
  parameters.putString("place",Cairo_ID);

Answer (score 0):

To tag your friends you need the id of the photo and the id of the Facebook friend. Following is a working code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < selectedFriendsIDs.size(); i++){

    String inputParm = uploadedImageID + "/tags?to=" + selectedFriendsIDs.get(i);

    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, accessToken);   
    mAsyncRunner.request(inputParm, params, "POST", new RequestListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e, Object state)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e, Object state)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(String response, Object state)
        {
            Log.d("Selected IDs ", "" + selectedFriendsIDs);
        }

        @Override
        public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }, null);
}
```